# Write a matrix without numpy o Python

Tags: python

I am trying to get my code to display a better looking matrix, but I just can't fix it.

My code so far is:

```
n = int(input("Digite o número de variáveis do sistema: "))
matriz_A=[]
for i in range(n):
   b=[]
   for j in range(n):
      j=float(input("Digite a entrada ["+str(i+1)+"]["+str(j+1)+"]"))
      b.append(j)
   matriz_A.append(b)
for i in  range(n):
   for j in range(n):
      print(matriz_A[i][j],end=" ")
   print()
```

But it's only displaying the numbers next to each other.

How can I solve this ?
Thank you !

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: You can add `print('[')` before the loop `j` and put it before `print(matriz_A ...)` when `j = 0`, and likewise for the `]`

Comment: Presumably you want to format your floats e.g. `f'{:.2f}'` so the matrix rows get displayed regularly, not ragged.

Comment: Hello, sorry if I am not replying correctly, I am new here.

Comment: My expected output would be the typical matrix shape that we use

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `print('[')` before the loop `i` and before the loop `j`, and likewise for the `]`.

```
matriz_A = [[1,2], [3,4]]
n = 2

print('[', end="")
for i in  range(n):
   if i > 0:
      print(' '*(n-1), end="")
   print('[', end=" ")
   for j in range(n):
      print(matriz_A[i][j],end=" ")
   print(']', end="")
   if i != n-1:
      print()
print(']')
```

Output:

```
[[ 1 2 ]
 [ 3 4 ]]
```

Comment: That was fast ! Thank you so much Dhana D. !